# excel formulaarray

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007, excel, vba

hi why do i get the runtime error 13: type mismatch error
while running the following code

```
 Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1:R232C221"
 Selection.FormulaArray = "=ROUND(a(),0)"
 Selection.Replace What:="a()", Replacement:="IF(IF(Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232=2,0," & _
"Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232)+IF(Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232=2,0," & _
"Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232)=2,0,IF(Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232=2,0," & _
"Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232)+IF(Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232=2,0,Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232))", LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Range("I9").Select
```

1) i know that formulaarray should be in R1C1 style... but A1 style is not required, it also works without any problems in A1 style

```
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208529.aspx
```

2) i found this way of writing from

```
  http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the "replacement" argument is too long.  You need to keep that string under 255 characters.  Put more of the formula into the Selection.FormulaArray line so that the replacement is less than 255 characters.

Answer (score 4):

Let's analyze your Replacement:

```
Replacement:="IF(IF(Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232=2,0," & _
"Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232)+IF(Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232=2,0," & _
"Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232)=2,0,IF(Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232=2,0," & _
"Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232)+IF(Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232=2,0,Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232))"
```

(1) change `Sheet4!A1:HM232+Sheet5!A1:HM232` to `X`:

```
Replacement:="IF(IF(X=2,0," & _
"X)+IF(X=2,0," & _
"X)=2,0,IF(X=2,0," & _
"X)+IF(X=2,0,X))"
```

(2) glue the broken pieces back together:

```
Replacement:="IF(IF(X=2,0,X)+IF(X=2,0,X)=2,0,IF(X=2,0,X)+IF(X=2,0,X))"
```

(3) change `IF(X=2,0,X)` to `Y`:

```
Replacement:="IF(Y+Y=2,0,Y+Y)"
```

(4) some evaluation:

- If X is 2, Y is 0, and the result is 0.
- If X is 1, Y is 1, and the result is
    0.
- If X is anything else, Y is X, and the
  result is 2*X.

(5) so the formula is equivalent to:

```
Replacement:="IF(OR(X=2,X=1),0,2*X)"
```

(6) so the next step would be to replace X (step 1 in reverse) ...

I'll just leave you with a question or two: How did it become so messy? Have you heard of "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself)?